# How do I call id element , in class element?

Tags: php, ajax

How do I make this `$(".spinner #6").hide();` ? Is there a way to make it that way ? because if I use like this `$(".spinner").attr("id", yes).show();` or `$(".spinner").attr("id", 6).show();`.. then all id="" , will appear. and if i use this code `$(".spinner").find("id", yes).css("display", "block");` nothing happened.  Is there a way to cope with this kind of thing ?

```
<div class="icon-groupx" id="6">
    <span class="ss-icon spinner" id="6" style"display:none;"></span>
    <span class="ss-icon ss-heart-no" id="6" style"display:none;"></span>
    <span class="ss-icon ss-heart-yes" id="6"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".ss-heart-yes").click(function() {
      var idclass=$(this).attr("id");
      var dataString = 'idclass='+ idclass;

      $(".spinner #6").show();
      $(".ss-heart-yes #6").hide();

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processed.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               if(result=='OK'){

                     $(".ss-heart-no #6").show();
                     $(".ss-heart-yes #6").hide();
                     $(".spinner #6")hide();
                     ///// OR /////
                     $(".ss-heart-no #idclass").show();
                     $(".ss-heart-yes #idclass").hide();
                     $(".spinner #idclass")hide();
                     ///// OR /////
                     $(".ss-heart-no idclass").show();
                     $(".ss-heart-yes idclass").hide();
                     $(".spinner idclass")hide();;


               } else {
                     echo "error";
               }
      }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, no wonder you're having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div class="icon-groupx" id="6">
    <span class="ss-icon spinner" id="spinner6" src="6" style"display:none;"></span>
    <span class="ss-icon ss-heart-no" id="heartno6" src="6" style"display:none;"></span>
    <span class="ss-icon ss-heart-yes" id="heartyes6" src="6" ></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".ss-heart-yes").click(function() {
      var ID=$(this).attr("src");
      var dataString = 'idclass='+ idclass;

      $("#spinner"+ID).show();
      $("#heartyes"+ID).hide();

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processed.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               if(result=='OK'){

                     $("#heartno"+ID).show();
                     $("#heartyes"+ID).hide();
                     $("#spinner"+ID)hide();;


               } else {
                     echo "error";
               }
      }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs in HTML are unique. The fact that you multiple of them corrupts your page, which is why it doesn't work.

See [this documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Answer (score 0):

id is always unique. you can hide and show using class itself.change the code as given below. for selecting a div class and hiding the span class which is inside another class . you can use  $(".icon-groupx > .ss-icon.spinner").show(); example

```
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

you should use like this

```
$('.outer > .inner')
```

And if a class contain space

```
ex:<class="text one" > then   $(".text.one").show(); is the way to use
```

your code change it as given below and try it

```
<div class="icon-groupx" id="6">
    <span class="ss-icon spinner" id="7" style="display:none;"></span>
    <span class="ss-icon ss-heart-no" id="8" style="display:none;"></span>
    <span class="ss-icon ss-heart-yes" id="9"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".ss-heart-yes").click(function() {
      var idclass=$(this).attr("id");
      var dataString = 'idclass='+ idclass;

      $(".icon-groupx > .ss-icon.spinner").show();
      $(".icon-groupx > .ss-icon.ss-heart-yes").hide();

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processed.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               if(result=='OK'){

                     $(".icon-groupx > .ss-icon.ss-heart-no").show();
                     $(".icon-groupx > .ss-icon.ss-heart-yes").hide();
                     $(".icon-groupx > .ss-icon.spinner")hide();


               } else {
                     echo "error";
               }
      }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: why i cant use this code? 
var idclass = $(this).attr("id"); $('#icon-'+idclass).hide();

Comment: @Googles var idclass = $(this).attr("id"); this line is correct .what is this $('#icon-'+idclass).hide();? see id should be unique. #icon . # is used to identfy id

Comment: I 've found the answer below. Thanks